# Neo4j getting killed in Travis CI container

Tags: neo4j, travis-ci

I'm trying to add Neo4j 3.0 to my tests for the `neo4j` gem and I'm having trouble with the server getting killed in a Travis CI container.  Pre-3.0 works just fine, but when I use 3.0 it seems to get killed.  There seems to be plenty of memory (when I run Neo4j locally it uses 300-400 MB).  I get a warning from Neo4j saying:

```
WARNING: Max 30000 open files allowed, minimum of 40000 recommended. See the Neo4j manual.
```

That makes me think that it's getting killed because of too many open files.  I'm not sure if there's a way to increase the number of files on a Neo4j container, and I have a number of jobs so I don't want to slow things down by running `sudo: true`.  Did Neo4j 3.0 change to require more open files (the documentation doesn't seem to imply that it did)?

**EDIT:**

My [`.travis.yml` file](https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j/blob/7.0.x/.travis.yml):

Answer (score 0):

I think our memory allocation is messing things up. One thing that is unusual on your (travis's) setup is that there is twice the amount of swap memory compared to RAM, and that the amount of memory reported as available is very large.

Try specifying the amount of memory in your config file. See http://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/#performance-tuning for more details, but essentially add these to your config.

In `neo4j.conf`:

`dbms.memory.pagecache.size=1G`

and in `neo4j-wrapper.conf`:

`dbms.memory.heap.max_size=1000
dbms.memory.heap.initial_size=1000`

The memory limits are set quite low to guarantee that Travis doesn't kill the process, and I suspect that the tests don't need much in terms of memory.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I just edited to include a link to the `.travis.yml` file that I'm using.  I did switch to `oraclejdk8` and so that's fine.  Part of the trick is that I would like to use the `neo4j-rake_tasks` gem to install Neo4j as that's part of the Neo4j.rb project.   When I run `neo4j console` (instead of start) to debug I can see that Travis is killing Neo4j with a 137 error code (which seems to be because of a system resource constraint)

Comment: Here's the link for [one of the the jobs](https://travis-ci.org/neo4jrb/neo4j/jobs/131225350), by the way.  You can see it getting killed because it's running as `console`.  You can't see the open files limit warning because it's going to STDERR, I think, but Travis support gave me the ability to SSH in and I can see it there.

Comment: Looking at one of your logs, I believe neo4j is working fine. The problem is that your script is calling `neo4j console` which is a blocking command. Neo4j sits and waits for 10 minutes, which is when travis goes in and kills the build because nothing as happened in 10 minutes. Change your script to `neo4j start` so that the next line in your script can be executed.

Comment: `neo4j start` also fails.  If I do a `neo4j status` just after running it and Neo4j is up, then I sleep for 10 seconds and do `neo4j status` again I find that the server is killed.  When I `ssh` in I see Neo4j being killed after less than 5 seconds.

Comment: One thing that strikes me is that there is an apparent pattern between the ruby versions. The runs using JRuby can even succeed: https://travis-ci.org/neo4jrb/neo4j/builds/130068974 For the other cases, what does the neo4j log say?

Comment: Unfortunately that's a bit misleading.  That's actually a bug in the testing that I need to fix.  The jruby versions are actually testing Neo4j in embedded mode and because of the the `gemspec` it's Neo4j version `2.2.4`.  Installing the server ahead of time wouldn't make any difference to the tests and I suspect it's failing there as well.  I *would* like to make Neo4j test both server and embedded modes for the jRuby version, but it's on my list of the many things that I have to do ;)

Comment: I fought for a while to get Travis to upload artifacts to S3, though when I did I found them mostly disappointing.  Included them here with dropbox links:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/w33mib9ido5ld21/debug.log?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/gpyieto78x1l9b9/neo4j.log?dl=0

Comment: Yes that was a thoroughly disappointing log file :( Still, we know it's only `neo4j start` which fails because `neo4j console` sits there for 10 minutes until travis times out. There was one issue recently which affected `start` and not `console`: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/7086 But you aren't starting it with the service script are you? Still, might be worth verifying that neo4j has write priviledges in its own directory, and that there is a run directory in its running directory.

Comment: `neo4j console` is most definitely failing quickly.  You might be seeing the job in which I was `ssh`ed in and where I was playing around with things.  I'll check the write permissions, though, thanks!

Comment: It looks like the `travis` user (which is what comes up when I run `whoami`) has `rw` permissions to everything in the directory.  Check out this gist: https://gist.github.com/cheerfulstoic/cad549c0918868ce1a85b681d21279d5

Comment: Ok, so I think I now know for sure that it's very quickly gobbling up memory!  I made [a gist](https://gist.github.com/cheerfulstoic/51a7fb19aabfeffc687db04155d66a4c) showing the output of `ps` every second until it dies.  I did a similar run for `lsof` and Neo4j only seemed to be using up to 186 files or so

Comment: I also added my `neo4j.conf` to the gist so that you could see it too.  Any ideas?

Comment: can you configure the page-cache and heap to the fixed size? if travis really reports 61GB of RAM then page-cache will take 50% of that and the JVM also a larger chunk

Comment: I think our memory allocation is messing things up. One thing that is unusual on your (travis's) setup is that there is twice the amount of swap memory compared to RAM, and that probably messes things up. Try specifying the amount of memory in your config file. See http://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/#performance-tuning for more details, but essentially add these to your config (some in `neo4j-wrapper.conf`): `dbms.memory.pagecache.size=1G`, `dbms.memory.heap.max_size=1000`, `dbms.memory.heap.initial_size=1000`

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it, and it works fine for me for 2.3 and 3.0 including a push to docker hub.

https://github.com/maxdemarzi/neo_travis

https://travis-ci.org/maxdemarzi/neo_travis